# why would I sometimes lose Navigation items when clicking to return to previous screen in UINavigationController app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Anyone know why would I sometimes lose Navigation items when clicking to return to previous screen in UINavigationController app?

Background:

- have a iPhone app using a UINavigationController and UITableViews
- 98% of the time things are fine, and if I'm on the detailed screen and click the "back" button things are find.  The app takes you back to the main screen (pop's a view off the stack)
- a small percentage of the time, and on the iPhone device itself, I click to go back, see some animation start, but I end up (a) on the same page, and (b) no navigation buttons or toolbar buttons appearing
- from this state you can't do anything obviously and have to kill the app and re-start

Any ideas?  How to fault find? (noting it's only occasionally when testing on an actual device I notice, and it may take hours/days before it does occur)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an alert in didReceiveMemoryWarning function of the viewController. The OS calls viewDidUnload on some memory warning (which don't usually happen in simulator).

Comment: hi Gary - so do you think such a memory warning could cause "funny" behaviour in the app?  i.e. wouldn't IOS either let the app function normally or kill it off if need be?  (I'm guessing here I mean, I'm not sure)

Comment: I saw something similar when I was using MKMapView where my bar button for IntelligentSplitViewController disappeared when memory warning occurred and reappeared on switching orientation. Anyway, it is just an idea for you to try out. I can't say conclusively that you have the same issue.

Comment: so did adding an alert actually help fix the issue Gary, or just at least let the user know what was going on and they should switch orientation?  did you ever fix the root cause?

Comment: I actually stopped using IntelligentSplitViewController since Apple anyway doesn't recommend using SplitViewController within tabbar. Kind of a different story. :)

Comment: You can try the following code for simulating memory warning in simulator. https://gist.github.com/956403